# I am new to c++ why is casting working in first case but not in second cout after masking one of the characters in char*

Tags: c++

why is casting working in the first case but not in second cout after masking one of the characters in char*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int n = 10;
   char* ch = (char*) calloc(6, sizeof(*ch));
   ch = strdup("ab");
   cout << strlen(ch) << endl;
   int* p = (int*) ch;
   cout << (char*)p << endl;// works fine it prints "ab" 
   *p = *p & 65280;
   cout << "cast not working\t" << (char*)p << endl; // it does not work  here
   free(ch);      
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? And why can you not be bothered to use capital letters and punctuation?

Comment: For C++ code, you should avoid using C-style casts. Use ``static_cast``, ``reinterpret_cast``, or ``const_cast``. The compiler can give you much better warnings with these than with the C-style casts which are overly aggressive.

Comment: You know you're only masking against the first aliased `char`, right? Which is way smaller than `65280`. Nothing you're doing in this code makes any sense whatsoever.

Comment: The interesting question is *how* is it not working, as in "what is the compiler error?"  Or "what output did @krish expect.?"

Comment: Come on, this code raises UB in second line of `main()`... I won't mention, that purpose of this... thing is at most confusing. @alain If that's an interesting question to you... dude, you need help.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I don't se any UB on that line

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: No, it doesn't. So check your facts before you go flinging personal attacks around.

Comment: There's a memory leak at line 3 of main though...

Comment: @krish instead of saying "does not work" - you should say what behaviour you observed, and what behaviour you expected. Also for this question it'd be useful to know what CPU architecture you have and what `sizeof(int)` is on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written as hex, `65280` is `0x0000FF00`. So, on common systems with `int` being 4 bytes, you have set `ch[0]` to be `0`. This is a null terminator, so when you try to print the string, you see an empty string.

Note: writing to `*p` causes undefined behaviour by writing past the end of the allocated area too; `strdup("ab")` allocates 3 bytes.  On common systems this probably will have no ill effect as heap allocations are done in chunks of a certain size.

Comment: Writing to `*p` *might* violate strict aliasing too, however C++ is unclear about aliasing in `malloc`'d space. It doesn't have the specific C99 aliasing rules for malloc'd space. So I give the benefit of the doubt...